# difference between single row transactions and multi row?

Tags: transactions, kudu, multirow

What is the difference between single row transactions and multi row transactions at databases by example please ?
As kudu support single row transactions but multi not supported ... and how kudu support atomic single row transactions but also don't support rollback?

Answer (score 0):

In context with the No-SQL database, I come across the term Single-row-transaction in Google BigTable.

In google documentation related to BigTable which is an abstraction of Hbase, they have provided pretty much a good explanation regarding Single-row-transaction.

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/app-profiles#single-row-transactions